# Como hacer SELECT Top 5 en MySQL

Tags: mysql

````
SELECT top 5 * C.Descripcion," ",M.Descripcion ," ",P.Descripcion as Producto , COUNT(IDPRODUCTO ```) AS NroVentas from VentaItems
inner join PRODUCTO AS P ON P.ID =VentaItems.IDPRODUCTO 
inner join CATEGORIA as C ON C.ID = P.IDCATEGORIA
inner join MARCA AS M ON M.ID = P.IDMARCA
Group by IDPRODUCTO,P.DESCRIPCION,C.Descripcion,M.Descripcion
Order by count(5) desc
````

alguna ayuda este es mi codigo

Comment: Muchas Gracias Eduardo , probe de esta manera pero no me salio, ahora coloque de esta manera y ahi me selecciono los 5 .                                                           
 Select CONCAT (C.Descripcion," ",M.Descripcion ," ",P.Descripcion) as Productos , COUNT(IDPRODUCTO ) AS NroVentas
from VentaItems
inner join PRODUCTO AS P ON P.ID =VentaItems.IDPRODUCTO
inner join CATEGORIA as C ON C.ID = P.IDCATEGORIA
inner join MARCA AS M ON M.ID = P.IDMARCA
Group by IDPRODUCTO,P.DESCRIPCION,C.Descripcion,M.Descripcion
Order by count(5) DESC
Limit 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya está ordenada solamente te falta poner un **LIMIT**:
(Editado tomando en cuenta los arreglos para que funcionara de verdad)

```
Select
  CONCAT (C.Descripcion," ",M.Descripcion ," ",P.Descripcion) as Productos,
  COUNT(IDPRODUCTO ) AS NroVentas
From
  VentaItems inner join PRODUCTO AS P
  ON P.ID =VentaItems.IDPRODUCTO inner join CATEGORIA as C
  ON C.ID = P.IDCATEGORIA inner join MARCA AS M
  ON M.ID = P.IDMARCA
Group by
  IDPRODUCTO,
  P.DESCRIPCION,
  C.Descripcion,
  M.Descripcion
Order by
  count(5) DESC
Limit 5
```

Comment: Esta consulta no es equivalente a SELECT TOP, falta un orden sobre la columna por la que se quiere ordenar.

Comment: Me parece que es diferente para distintas bases de datos. Puedes ver una comparación de varios servidores SQL aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp. Para MySQL se usa "LIMIT" mientras que otras bases de datos usan algo distinto. El orden en este caso está definido por "Order by count(5) DESC".

Comment: ¿Qué representa `count(5)` exactamente?

Comment: Sería el equivalente a hacer el "COUNT" sobre la quinta columna si hicieras "SELECT *" para los valores que no sean null. Personalmente yo prefiero usar nombres explícitos pero el estándar lo permite de ambas formas.

Answer (score 0):

````
Select CONCAT (C.Descripcion," ",M.Descripcion ," ",P.Descripcion) as Productos , COUNT(IDPRODUCTO ) AS NroVentas from VentaItems inner join PRODUCTO AS P ON P.ID =VentaItems.IDPRODUCTO inner join CATEGORIA as C ON C.ID = P.IDCATEGORIA inner join MARCA AS M ON M.ID = P.IDMARCA Group by IDPRODUCTO,P.DESCRIPCION,C.Descripcion,M.Descripcion Order by count(5) DESC Limit 5```
````